# Editing yaml hashmap with ruby and rake

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap, rake

I have a yaml who's elements need to be filled by a user... sounds simple enough. I am attempting to read the file, print the keys, ask for a value, and store the updated file.

cnfg.yml:

```
thing:
  something:
  another_thing:
    much_depth:

such_yml:
...
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
task :setup_cnfg do
  config = YAML.load_file 'cnfg.yml'

  config.each do |key, value|
    puts key
    value.each do |k, v|
      print "   #{k}: "
      v = STDIN.gets.chomp() #STDIN is there due to some strange rake shenanigans       
    end
  end
  File.open('cnfg.yml','w') {|f| f.write config.to_yaml}
end
```

If I print 'v' after I capture the input it does show the intended value but if i print the hash afterwords all imputed values will be gone!

What would I do in order to correctly populate and store all of my data fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually *assign* the new `v` back to the `value` hash:

```
task :setup_cnfg do
  config = YAML.load_file 'cnfg.yml'

  config.each do |key, value|
    puts key
    value.each do |k, _|
      print "   #{k}: "
      value[k] = STDIN.gets.chomp() 
    end
  end
  File.open('cnfg.yml','w') {|f| f.write config.to_yaml}
end
```